# Changing the color of a specific piece of text in emacs without creating a theme

Tags: emacs, terminal

Is it possible to select a piece of text you're editing and change its color? I know it's possible to create a color theme that will color certain kinds of text (like for example coloring functions in a certain programming language), but is it possible to do a one time color change to a selected piece of text in a specific emacs document without creating a theme? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

A theme doesn't allow you to specify the color of arbitrary text in any case.  It only describes a set of face to be used by font-lock.

To apply a face to an arbitrary piece of text, **select the text**, then <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(add-text-properties (region-beginning) (region-end) '(face font-lock-warning-face))`

See the faces section of the elisp manual on how to create a face.

Emacs also comes with the `hi-lock` package, which can highlight regexps or lines containing regexps.  See [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/Highlight-Interactively.html)

Comment: I'm pretty certain that won't work, since `add-text-properties` isn't `interactive` .  Might work with `M-:` (`eval`).

Comment: By select the text, do you mean by setting a mark at the beginning of the text and then moving the cursor to the end of the selection?

Comment: @user534398 that's indeed what he means.  You might want to read up on the section of the manual, though, as this limits what face you're getting.

Comment: @CharlieMartin yes, of course, M-:.  I just assumed he really wants `hi-lock` anyway.

Comment: Alright, I've been trying out lots of things and getting closer to my solution. Ultimately, I'm still very inexperienced with emacs. I have a very novice question which is: What does M-: represent? I know that M-x represents holding the meta key and pressing x, but I'm confused about M-: and what this means. I tried holding down the meta key and typing a colon, but I received this message: "No comment syntax defined use:" and a prompt. Can someone explain this? Thanks so much!

Comment: M-: means Alt colon, correct.  It sounds like you're pressing semi-colon.  Hold down shift at the same time to get colon.

Comment: Honestly I still can't get this to work, despite trying several times. When I enter the commands above I get the output "nil" at the bottom of the screen. I press M-: which brings up eval and then enter the command exactly as you've written it. Is it necessary to create a face for this to work? I suppose I expected there to be a quick and easy way to select text and change its color (not the background color of the text) but perhaps that's not the case. For the sake of resolving the question, I'd still like to find something that works even if it's complex.

Comment: @Hendeca I tried the above and it worked. It changed the face and color of my font. When writing out the command, I suggest just putting in the first few letters, then pressing TAB for auto-complete options, to avoid typos, and maybe figure out which part of the command is the problematic one.

Answer (score 8):

how about `M-x highlight-phrase` ?

Comment: I was going to accept but realized this technically just changes the background color of the text, not the text itself. Perhaps there's not a way to do this quickly and easily?

Answer (score 5):

I know six years is a pretty long time, but I stumbled across this question and, after a lot of research, I did not find anything nearly as objective as what I eventually dug out for myself.

To color say, the first 200 characters in your buffer, execute the command:

```
(put-text-property 1 200 'face (cons 'foreground-color "red"))
```

If you need help executing this command in emacs, here is one possibility among many:

1. Type ESC-x eval-expression.
2. Type or paste the above command in the mini-buffer after the prompt.
3. Press ENTER.

Comment: If this does not work, try M-x font-lock-mode RET to disable (toggle) font lock mode, which clobbers all colors & faces when enabled.  Also, (cons 'foreground-color "red") is deprecated in favor of (list :foreground "red") which allows, e.g., (list :foreground "red" :background "orange" :slant 'italic)

Answer (score 4):

You might like to look at [enriched-mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Enriched-Mode.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a buffer that isn't controlled by font-lock, you can use 'facemenu'.

For example, highlight a bit of text, then with the mouse, press `C-mouse-2`.  You can then select a face (some combination of text properties with a name).  You can also pick random forground or background colors.

If you Emacs is particularly old, I seem to remember something similar on `M-g`.

Comment: C-mouse-2 allows me to change he foreground color, but only temporarily.  Once I exit emacs, the foreground color change is lost.  I suspect this is expected as nothing is added to the file to "save" the foreground color change.

Answer (score 0):

Try `set-background-color`, `set-foreground-color`, `set-cursor-color`.
Changes won't be saved with the document though.

Note:
When I try those functions, they don't set the region's color unless I go through the menus.

Comment: I was able to get this to work, but only for the entire document. Maybe I'm not selecting a region succesfully? I tried setting a mark at the beginning of the region I want to edit and then moving the cursor to the end of the region I want but his didn't work. Neither did highlighting with the mouse. Any tips for this? Also unfortunately it does seem as though this isn't permanent, so that's another problem

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightTemporarily (and it need not be temporary).

You can "color" text by swiping it with the mouse, or matching it with a regexp, and several other ways. Library [`highlight.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary), in particular, lets you "color" text in many ways.