# Font lock with org-agenda not working

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode, font-lock

I have a org file with the following content:

```
* My Heading
** TODO Make a FOO
** TODO Take action on bar and FOO
** TODO Check if FOO is working
```

My objective is to highlight the word `FOO` from the task headings in `org-agenda-mode`. To achieve this, I've tried:

```lisp
(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (font-lock-add-keywords nil
                            '(("\\(FOO\\)" 1 '(:background "red"))))))
```

But nothing changes. My hook **is** running and if I try `C-h v font-lock-keywords` inside  the agenda view, the value returned is

```lisp
(t
 (("\\(FOO\\)" 1
   '(:background "red")))
 ("\\(FOO\\)"
  (1
   '(:background "red"))))
```

Apart from showing the same item two times, I can't see why this isn't working. Does *ignore* `font-lock-mode` settings? If so, how could I add a "custom" keyword hightlight to `org-agenda-mode`?

**EDIT :**

- `M-x emacs-version` is `GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (i686-pc-mingw32)`
- `M-x org-version` is `Org-mode version 8.2.10`

Comment: `*Org-Agenda*` buffers use `text-properties` without font-lock.  Is `font-lock-mode` enabled in that particular buffer? -- e.g., `M-x describe-variable RET font-lock-mode RET`

Comment: @lawlist Touché. `font-lock-mode` is disabled. Thanks to your tip, I've able to find a answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @lawlist suggested, the `*Org-Agenda*` buffer does not use `font-lock-mode`. The easiest way to achieve what I want in the agenda view is to use [HiLock](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HiLock) as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707002/changing-the-color-of-a-specific-piece-of-text-in-emacs-without-creating-a-theme):

```
(defface my-hi-lock-face '((t (:background  "red"
                               :foreground  "yellow"
                               :bold t)))
                          "my-hi-lock-face")

(add-hook 'org-finalize-agenda-hook
          (lambda ()
            (highlight-regexp "\\(FOO\\)" "my-hi-lock-face")))
```

Note the hook I'm using: this one runs again everytime I redraw my agenda buffer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps me highlight some strings in my Org Agenda.

Comment: Just a reminder: now the hook name has changed to `org-agenda-finalize-hook`, revise this in the code provided above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the time to try and understand what's wrong in your code, but you can have a look at my Emacs-Leuven.el file (L976-1015): I do the same for the words "FIXME", "XXX" and "BUG".

https://github.com/fniessen/emacs-leuven/blob/master/emacs-leuven.el

Comment: As per @lawlist comment, the problem is that `org-agenda` does not use `font-lock-mode`.

Comment: Rigth. I missed the fact you needed it in the agenda. Thanks for correcting me.